# facebook login using graph Api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to have facebook login using graph Api because I want user_birthday and user_location. Before I was using this link to login: 
       http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

But I was not getting additional information like birth date and location. So I am approaching  towards graph Api. But didn't find any tutorial for it. I tried some link and build some code but getting session null. I am sure thats a implementation issue. Here is my code:

```
     fbLogin.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                openActiveSession(LoginScreenActivity.this, true, fbStatusCallback, Arrays.asList(
                        new String[] { "email",  "user_location", "user_birthday"}), savedInstanceState);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("exception", e.getMessage());
            }                   
        Intent intent=new Intent(LoginScreenActivity.this,DealGaliTabActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

  private  Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI,
              StatusCallback callback, List<String> permissions, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(activity)
            .setPermissions(permissions).setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior
            .SSO_WITH_FALLBACK).setCallback(callback)
            .setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);

                 Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                 Log.d("session", "" + session);
                 if (session == null) {
                     Log.d("sussion_Null", "" + savedInstanceState);
                     if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                         session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, fbStatusCallback, savedInstanceState);
                     }
                     session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(LoginScreenActivity.this);
                     Session.setActiveSession(session);
                     Log.d("sessionSet", "" + session);

                     if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED) || allowLoginUI) {
                         session.openForRead(openRequest);
                         return session;
                     }
                 }
                 return session;
             }
             @Override
             public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                 Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
             }

             private Session.StatusCallback fbStatusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                        if (state.isOpened()) {
                            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                                    if (response != null) {
                                     Log.i("Graphresponse", response.toString());
                                        try{
                                            get_id = user.getId();
                                            get_name = user.getName();
                                            get_gender = (String) user.getProperty("gender");
                                            get_email = (String) user.getProperty("email");
                                            get_birthday = user.getBirthday();
                                            get_locale = (String) user.getProperty("locale");
                                            get_location = user.getLocation().toString();   

                                        Log.d("GraphSelected", user.getId() + "; " +  
                                            user.getName() + "; " +
                                            (String) user.getProperty("gender") + "; " +        
                                            (String) user.getProperty("email") + "; " +
                                            user.getBirthday()+ "; " +
                                            (String) user.getProperty("locale") + "; " +
                                            user.getLocation());
                                        } catch(Exception e) {
                                             e.printStackTrace();
                                             Log.d("GraphException", e.getMessage());
                                         }

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                };
```

I am also not getting facebook screen for first time login..please suggest me some solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if `getBirthday()`, `getLocation()` are the valid methods, but you can directly access these properties as-

```
get_birthday = (String) user.getProperty("birthday");
get_location = (String) user.getProperty("location").getProperty("name");
```

I'm also not really sure `user.getProperty("location").getProperty("name")` is valid thing to do, actually the response of location is of form:

```
"location": {
     "id": 123456789,
     "name": "Blah"
}
```

This should get you the birthday and location.

---

Also, check if you can see the bday and location permission granted or not in the [app settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I want..I hope it would be helpful to others...

```
public void readData(){
     if (Session.getActiveSession() == null
                || Session.getActiveSession().isClosed()) {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new StatusCallback() {

                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                        Exception exception) {
                    System.out.println("State= " + state);

                    if (session.isOpened()) {

                        System.out.println("Token=" + session.getAccessToken());
                        if(session.getAccessToken() != null){
                            sharedPrefernces();
                        }
                            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                                if (response != null) {
                                 Log.i("Graphresponse", response.toString());
                                    try{
                                        get_id = user.getId();
                                        get_name = user.getName();
                                        get_gender = (String) user.getProperty("gender");
                                        get_email = (String) user.getProperty("email");
                                        get_birthday = user.getBirthday();
                                        get_locale = (String) user.getProperty("locale");
                                        get_location = user.getLocation().toString(); 

                                        URL img_value = null;
                                        img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+get_id+"/picture?type=large");
                                        mImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());

                                    Log.d("GraphSelected", get_id + "  " +  
                                        get_name + "  " +
                                        get_gender + "  " +        
                                        get_email + "  " +
                                        get_birthday + "  " +
                                        get_locale + "  " +
                                        get_location);
                                    } catch(Exception e) {
                                         e.printStackTrace();
                                         Log.d("GraphException", e.getMessage());
                                     }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if (exception != null) {
                        System.out.println("Some thing bad happened!");
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
     }
```