# Why am I not able to clear Facebook access token data on Logout

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am trying to clear the access token data during log out in my app. But for some reason its not getting cleared.
The next time I click on Facebook login button it is directly signing me in.

```
public void FBClearData() {
    GraphRequest delPermRequest = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/{user-id}/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
            if (graphResponse != null) {
                FacebookRequestError error = graphResponse.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    flash(error.toString());
                }
                FBLogout();
            }
        }
    });
    delPermRequest.executeAsync();
}

public void FBLogout()
{

    if(loginResult.getAccessToken() != null){
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    }
}
```

I want to clear the access token data and logout the user account. So that next time user tries to login the user is shown the facebook permissions screen again!

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647404/facebook-login-using-graph-api